# Filter and Print spreadsheet automatically

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with values in 3 columns. I want to filter and print with VBA loop code. The code I wrote is below. If I use numeric value for `criteria 1:="<26"` then it filters all the values below `26`. But I wanted it to work with loop value for example value below `26` than `27 to 50` and so on.

Once filter I can use print command and then move on to the next value filter and print and so on until all printed up to the last row. Not sure how to resolve this bit.

```
Sub loopi()    
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim lrow As Integer

    i = 1        
    lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Do While i < lrow        
        i = i + 25        
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<i"        
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False  
    Loop    
End Sub
```

Comment: First of all `i` is not recognized as variable in `Criteria1:="<i"` but as character `i`. You must change it to `Criteria1:="<" & i` in order to use the counter `i` from the loop as criteria. • Secondly your row counting variables need to be of type `Long` because Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle.

Comment: Thanks PEH, it is working, I got the understanding here. Now the next thing what I wanted to achieve is once the first 25 value filtered and printed, then the next 25 should be chosen instead of 50 all together. Basically 1st page 25 then print, 2nd page 26-50 then print and so on. any idea how can I enhance the above code further. Thanks Manpreet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `i` is not recognized as variable in `Criteria1:="<i"` but as character `i`. You must change it to `Criteria1:="<" & i` in order to use the counter `i` from the loop as criteria.
2. Your row counting variables need to be of type `Long` because Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle.
3. If you want data eg from 25…50 then you need 2 critaria with an `And` operator in your filter. So you need to calculate the start and the end criteria.

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub PrintSplitData()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
       'better to name the sheet unless you do it on many different sheets
       'Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("YouDataSheetName")

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim iStartRow As Long, iEndRow As Long
    For iStartRow = 1 To LastRow Step 25
        iEndRow = iStartRow + 24
        iEndRow = IIf(iEndRow > LastRow, LastRow, iEndRow) 'limit it to LastRow

        Debug.Print iStartRow, iEndRow 'this is just for illustrating

        ws.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & iStartRow, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & iEndRow
        ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    Next iStartRow
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Peh, it is working. Can you also tell me how can i improve my coding skills? the only source so far i am using is Internet. Thanks for you help before.